# TR + SED in one time on large file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, tr

I need to execute 2 unix commands on large file (.csv delimited with `\0001`, few million lines, more than 15gb, on server with 24cores 512gb of ram).

I need to `tr` ( replace `\0001` by `/t` ) and then `sed` to add a little string to the end of each line.

The problem is that I'm running a first time the TR then, after parsing all line of the file to a new file, i exec the `sed` command to add to each line. That's taking a lot of time!

Is there a way i can parse each line of the file only once for exec `tr` and `sed`?

Comment: Just out of interest: What kind of measurement is "go"?

Comment: Hi :) okay, i'm french, Giga Octets = Giga Bytes = 8 * Giga Bits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sed` only and apply two actions per line:

```
sed 's/\\0001/\t/g;s/$/TEXT_TO_APPEND/' input.file
```

The first `s/` command replaces `\0001` by `\t`, the second one allows you to append some text.

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/$/TEXT_TO_APPEND/' file` might be quicker than using a back reference. BTW `&` is a synonym for `\0`.

Comment: @potong Good point! At least it looks cleaner. Added that. thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use unix pipes to connect the `STOUT` of `tr` to the `STDIN` of `sed`:

```
cat input.file | tr -opt -ions | sed 's/../../g' > output.file
```

Comment: id like to, but i cant upvote because of my reputation under 15, sry :/

Comment: it does not respect the request of avoiding to start the 2 application. (but is a welcome comment as information)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu if you carefully read the question, you realize it is *not* about "avoiding to execute two binarys". However, I support your argument because using a single `sed` command performs much better. Still, the reference to unix piping will help beginners to understand such requirements better.